# Using Switch Statements in Swift - Value binding INSIDE the parentheses vs outside?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I'm wondering what in the world the difference is between these two following examples. If there is no difference, simply say no difference, and I'll give the answer to you. Notice in case two, the let value binding is declared INSIDE the parenthesis of the tuple pattern, whereas in case one, the let is declared outside of the tuple. When I play around with both of these examples, they both yield the exact same results.
Thanks.

Case 1)

```
let myNumbers = (1, 2)
switch myNumbers {
   case let (x, 2):
      print("the value of x is \(x)")
   default:
      print("n/a")
}
```

Case 2)

```
let myNumbers = (1, 2)
 switch myNumbers {
    case (let x, 2):
       print("the value of x is \(x)")
    default:
       print("n/a")
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 is more concise, and better suited for the general case.

Case 2 is more granular. Consider this case:

```
switch myNumbers {
    case (let x, var y):
        // x is a constant, y is mutable.
        print("the value of x is \(x)")
    default:
        print("n/a")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer when the 12 minute restriction ends. Makes sense.

Comment: Just to be clear, by 'granular' you basically mean you have more intimate control over the circumstances, right? In case 1, the entire tuple being declared as a let, you are not able to modify 'x'. However in case 2, you are value binding to a tuple where the 'y' value is modifiable inside the execution block. Right?

Comment: @user7024499 Yep. The first case makes a blanket statement for all bound variables. Either they're all `let`, or they're all `var`. The second case lets you mix by specifying each one explicitly.

Comment: This is an opinion, but OP's case 2 seems clearer to me. Especially in this case where you're only casting one variable, it's the same number of characters and it more clearly indicates what's happening.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ From my experience, in every situation I've run into where I've 1) wanted to do value binding and 2) had a tuple of 2 or more values, I've needed to bind both values, in which case the 1st method would be better.

Comment: I agree when there are multiple values you want to bind :)